# Update all of my node properties with both the number of relationships to and from that node

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher, relationship, store

So I was thinking of something alone the lines of:

MATCH (a:Entity)<--(x:Entity)  SET a.links_to=count(x)
MATCH (a:Entity)-->(x:Entity)  SET a.links_from=count(x)

How might I write this correctly in Cypher?
How might I do this in a fast and preferably parallel fashion, perhaps by using Apoc ?

Comment: Are :Entity nodes the only nodes which are connected to other :Entities? If so, then there's no need to do this at all, as the relationship degree data is already on the node itself, you just need to look that up in your query. If this is the case, let me know and I'll add how to do this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very effectively with.

```
Match (e:Entity)
Set e.links_to = size((e)<--()),
      e.links_from = size((e)-->())
```

If you want to use APOC to speed it up and run in parallel

```
Call apoc.periodic.iterate(
' match (e:Entity) return e',
' set e.links_to = size((e)<--()),
      e.links_from = size((e)-->())',
{batchSize:10000,parallel: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expensive operation to do but if you want to do it here is the cypher query for it:

```
match (a)-[]->(b) 
with a, b, 
CASE WHEN exists(a.outgoingEdges) THEN a.outgoingEdges+1 else 1 END as outgoingEdges,
CASE WHEN exists(b.incomingEdges) THEN b.incomingEdges+1 else 1 END as incomingEdges
SET
 a.outgoingEdges= outgoingEdges,
 b.incomingEdges = incomingEdges
```

Answer (score 0):

Great responses. The Apoc solution works particularly well.  Many thanks !

Comment: you can upvote and set the answer as correct is this is your answer